# Access 2007 to 2010 Conversion Compile Error: User-defined type not defined

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I recently converted (exported/imported) a 2007 Access file to 2010. Everything works fine except one form. I keep getting the error:

> Compile error: User-defined type not defined

I tried adding "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8" to my References, but the problem still exists.  `Sub ClearTreeView(tvwTree As TreeView)` is what Access highlighted as the issue.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

' Clears all nodes on a treeview control
Sub ClearTreeView(tvwTree As TreeView) 'what Access highlighted as the issue
    On Error GoTo EH
    tvwTree.Nodes.Clear
    Exit Sub
EH:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
End Sub

' Calls functions to clear and populate a treeview control
' Parameters:
'       strForm         Name of the form
'       strTV           TreeView control name
'       strSourceName   Name of the table or query containing the data used to populate the treeview
'       strChildField   ID field for the child records
'       strParentField  Parent ID Field
'       strTextField    Field containing text that will be used as node labels
'
Sub FillTreeView(tvwTree As Object, strSourceName As String, strChildField As String, strParentField As String, strTextField As String)
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    
    On Error GoTo EH
    
    ' Open the recordset using table and fields specified in Sub parameters
    strSQL = "SELECT " & strChildField & ", " & strParentField & ", " & strTextField & " FROM " & strSourceName
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
    
    ' Clear any existing data out of the treeview
    ClearTreeView tvwTree
    
    ' Call recursive function to fill in treeview
    AddTreeData tvwTree, rs, strChildField, strParentField, strTextField
    
    ' Close the recordset
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Exit Sub
EH:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
End Sub


' Recursive function to populate a treeview control
' Parameters:
'       strFormName     Name of the form
'       strTreeViewName TreeView control name
'       rs              Recordset containing the data used to populate the treeview
'       strChildField   ID field for the child records
'       strParentField  Parent ID Field
'       strTextField    Field containing text that will be used as node labels
'       varParentID     Optional parameter that only gets passed for recursive calls to this function.  Specifies the ID of the current record to be used as a
'                       ParentID when searching the recordset for "grand-children", etc.
Sub AddTreeData(objTV As TreeView, rs As DAO.Recordset, strChildField As String, strParentField As String, strTextField As String, Optional varParentID As Variant)
    Dim nodChild As Node
    Dim nodParent As Node
    Dim strLabel As String
    Dim strNodeID As String
    Dim strCriteria As String
    Dim strBookmark As String
    
    On Error GoTo EH
    
    ' Test for a circular reference
    If rs(strChildField) = rs(strParentField) Then GoTo EH_CircularReference
    
    ' If the optional parameter is missing, then this is the first(non-recursive) call to this function.
    ' Set the critieria to look for a parent id of 0.
    If IsMissing(varParentID) Then
        strCriteria = strParentField & " = 0 "
    Else
        ' Otherwise, extract the childID portion of the node ID, which was passed as an optional parameter.
        strCriteria = strParentField & " = " & Mid(varParentID, InStr(1, varParentID, "C") + 1)
        ' Define the parent node
        Set nodParent = objTV.Nodes("node" & varParentID)
    End If
    
    ' Look for records having the specified "parent"
    rs.FindFirst strCriteria
    Do Until rs.NoMatch
        ' Read node caption from the text field
        strLabel = rs(strTextField)
        ' Create a new node ID in the format ParentID &"C" & ChildID (eg: 4C12)
        strNodeID = "node" & rs(strParentField) & "C" & rs(strChildField)
        
        ' If optional parameter is missing (first call to this function)...
        If Not IsMissing(varParentID) Then
            'add new node to the next higher node for this record
            Set nodChild = objTV.Nodes.Add(nodParent, tvwChild, strNodeID, strLabel)
        Else
            ' Otherwise, add new node to the top level of the tree
            Set nodChild = objTV.Nodes.Add(, , strNodeID, strLabel)
        End If
        
        ' Bookmark our place in the recordset so that we can resume the search from the same point after the recursive call to this function.
        strBookmark = rs.Bookmark
        
        ' call this function recursively for "children"
        AddTreeData objTV, rs, strChildField, strParentField, strTextField, rs(strParentField) & "C" & rs(strChildField)
        
        ' Return to bookmared place in the recordset
        rs.Bookmark = strBookmark
        
        ' Find the next record having the same parentID
        rs.FindNext strCriteria
    Loop
    
    Exit Sub
    
EH_CircularReference:
    MsgBox "Exiting because of a circular reference in which a child record was determined to be it's own parent."
    Exit Sub

    
EH:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

I received the same error on one of my User Forms in Excel!

If your new 2010 Office package is 64Bit, then the previous 32-Bit ActiveX Controls used in the 2007 version will not be compatible.

Refer to this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee691831(office.14).aspx#odc_office2010_Compatibility32bit64bit_ActiveXControlCOMAddinCompatibility

If you try opening the form in design view and the TreeView control doesn't exist on the form, then this is likely to be the issue.

To find if you installed the 64-bit version:
Open Access -> File -> Help -> and look under "About Microsoft Access" on the right - it should say 32-Bit or 64-Bit in brackets

As the link explains, you will have to replace the incompatible functionality - so you will have to use a new control.

**Possible Solution:**

If you open the form in design view, and select the down arrow on the Controls Group in the Ribbon Tab - there should be an option named "ActiveX Controls" (You have to be in design view to select it)

Search here for the "CTreeView" Control and try working with that instead of the traditional Microsoft TreeView Control (which shouldn't be listed on 64-Bit Access).

If you have 32-Bit office installed, then I can't figure out the problem with what you have posted - but I suspect it's the case.

Best Regards,